# Certain subrings of $k[t]$

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero, and let $t$ be a variable over $k$.

Clearly, $k[t^2,t^3] \subsetneq k[t]$ is not a UFD, since $t^2t^2t^2=t^3t^3$.

Let $h(t) \in k[t]$ with $\deg_t(h) \geq 2$.

Is it possible to somehow characterize all such $h$'s such that $k[t^2,t^3][h]$ is a UFD?
(Are there such $h$'s at all?).

Any hints and comments are welcome!

Comment: How about $t^2+t$?

Comment: Isn't $k[t^2,t^3][h]$ always equal to either $k[t^2,t^3]$ or $k[t]$?

Comment: See also [this related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1538730/showing-that-x2-and-x3-are-irreducible-but-not-prime-in-kx2-x3).

Comment: Thank you very much: yoyo, Eric Wofsey and Dietrich Burde.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the vector space $k[t]/k[t^2,t^3]$ is $1$-dimensional (spanned by $t$), it has only two subspaces, so there are only two possible values of $k[t^2,t^3][h]$: either $k[t^2,t^3]$ or $k[t]$.  Explicitly, $k[t^2,t^3][h]=k[t]$ (and is thus a UFD) if $h$ has a linear term and $k[t^2,t^3][h]=k[t^2,t^3]$ if it does not.

Comment: Thank you very much.